# Description Logics UTF-8 parser

Tags: utf-8, owl, converters, description-logic, reasoner

Trying to deepen my comprehension of OWL and Description Logics, I'm disappointed I cannot find a Description Logics parser which could convert DL to a web ontology syntax ("DL *German* syntax" if I'm not wrong).

For getting acquainted with the notation, on Windows, I use AutoHotkey with sends UTF-8 symbols to the editor (ex: `Send {U+2200}` writes `∀`). This works well with Sublime Text, VSCode or Notepad3 to name a few, with a supporting font of course, but can I go further and use a reasoner from DL Syntax directly or through a converter back and forth to at least one usable syntax like the Manchester notation ?